# Import issue with com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizeConfig

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I'm working on a Spring boot tutorial and I'm a bit stuck on this section of the video. The narrator in the video uses the MaxSizeConfig import inside a return statement. Trying out the same line, I'm getting an error saying that MaxSizeConfig can't be resolved to a type. Checking out the docs for hazelcast, the import exists. Could I get some direction in what I'm doing wrong with my code?

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.stephen.springweb</groupId>
<artifactId>productrestapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>productrestapi</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>
                    org.springframework.boot
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    spring-boot-starter-tomcat
                </artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the code that's trying to use MaxSizeConfig:

```
package com.stephen.springweb.productrestapi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.EvictionPolicy;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizePolicy;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ProductCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public Config cacheConfig() {
        return new Config()
                    .setInstanceName("hazel-instance")
                    .addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
                        .setName("product-cache")
                        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(3000)
                        .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                    );
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For version 4, use setEvictionConfig.
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/EvictionConfig.html

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.EvictionConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.EvictionPolicy;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.config.MaxSizePolicy;

@Configuration
public class ProductCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public Config cacheConfig() {
        return new Config()
                .setInstanceName("hazel-instance")
                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
                        .setName("product-cache")
                        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(3000)
                        .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                                .setSize(200)
                                .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE)
                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                        )
                );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of hazelcast are you using? More precisely, which is inherited from Spring. The setMaxSizeConfig method has been removed in later versions of hazelcast, for example 4.2 https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/MapConfig.html

But in version 3.6 it was still https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/MapConfig.html

The differences between versions 3 and 4 are significant.

Comment: I didn't specify a version in the pom so it probably uses the most recent version. I had a feeling that it had to do with versions since I've had to change up some stuff to match recent versions in some of the previous tutorials. Thank you. Would you happen to know what I can substitute that line with to perform the same entry function on the most recent hazelcast release?

Comment: @StephenAgbenu see documentation https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.html#map-eviction

Maybe you should just remove this setter if you are just getting familiar with hazelcast and come back to it later.